# Magento 2: how to check if there is a role in site

Tags: magento2, user-roles, role

I used the following code in magento 1 to check role is avilable or not.

```
$role = Mage::getModel('api/roles')->load('my new role', 'role_name');
if(!$role->getId())
```

I want to know, How can I archive this in Magento 2.

Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are no API services for `Authorization` module. You can try to use role collection for search roles by name. Keep in mind that you need to inject `\Magento\Authorization\Model\ResourceModel\Role\CollectionFactory` via constructor.

```
/**
 * Is role exist.
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return bool
 */
public function isRoleExist($name)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Authorization\Model\ResourceModel\Role\CollectionFactory $this->roleCollectionFactory */
    /** @var \Magento\Authorization\Model\ResourceModel\Role\Collection $roleCollection */
    $roleCollection = $this->roleCollectionFactory->create();
    $roleCollection->addFieldToFilter('role_name', $name);
    return $roleCollection->count() > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code started from here :

```
namespace Aaaa\Bbbbb\Controller\Adminhtml\Save;
use Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface;
use Magento\Authorization\Model\Role\Interceptor;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $roleCollection;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\Role\User\CollectionFactory $roleCollection
    ) {
        $this->roleCollection = $roleCollection;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->roleCollection->create();

        $collection->addFieldToFilter('role_name','oooaaa bbbb');
    }
}
```

The code end here..

This is not working ? he sent fatal error...

Answer (score 0):

@MEIR @Prashant Valanda use class

> Magento\Authorization\Model\ResourceModel\Role\CollectionFactory

instead of

> Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\Role\User\CollectionFactory

@MEIR delete `var/generation`(2.2) or `generated`(2.1) folder content whenever you change a constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code

```
protected $roleCollection;

    protected function __construct(
        \Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\Role\User\CollectionFactory $roleCollection
    )
    {
         $this->roleCollection = $roleCollection;
    }

    public function execute(){
           $collection = $this->roleCollection->create();

          $collection->addFieldToFilter('role_name','my new role');
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Prashant Valanda, I want to write only in the execute ? How can I do it please.. ? Thanks...

Comment: @Prashant Valanda 1. Arguments do not injected via "_construct", only using class constructor "__construct". 2. Injected collection factory, but used collection. 3. You need to filter collection, in this case will be loaded all role entities.

Comment: @MaxStsepantsevich 1 is typo mistake and updated answer

Comment: Thanks @PrashantValanda, But I still don't understand... I got this error: Recoverable Error: Argument 3 passed to Aaaa\Bbbb\Controller\Adminhtml\Save\Save::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\Role\User\CollectionFactory.. There is a problem with 3 arguments...  this is my class :class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action

Comment: @MEIR please add your code to question

Comment: I add a new code in top comment...

Comment: @MEIR Have you cleared var/generation folder ?

Comment: No I didn't clear this folder @PrashantValanda, what this folder means ?

Comment: clear that folder.please refer http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html